# how to access this JSON structure via jquery/javascript without using a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON structure which I'm trying to access without much success.

```
{
   "COURSEDETAILS": {
      "BTR": {
         "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Health Sciences",
       },
      "BYTR": {
         "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Nursing (Preregistration)",
      }
   },
   "STUDENT": [
      {
         "WSDCOURSECODE": "BTR",
         "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
      },
      {
         "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
         "WSDCOURSECODE": "BYTR",
      }
   ]
}
```

I can easily access the the student part. But no idea on how to access CDFULLTITLE for **every** situation. **I do not want to iterate using a for loop.**

BHS and BNGU changes for every student. So student with ID 234456 might have WSDCOURSECODE = XXXX.

I can access the course code on the student section via data.STUDENT[0].WSDCOURSECODE. But I have no idea on how to use this to access the CDFULLTITLE in COURSEDETAILS.

Maybe the problem is my structure. Please advise on a better way of doing it?

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking how to loop through properties in a JavaScript object?  You can use `for`-`in` and access the properties in that way.

```js
var data = {
   "COURSEDETAILS": {
      "BTR": {
         "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Health Sciences",
       },
      "BYTR": {
         "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Nursing (Preregistration)",
      }
   },
   "STUDENT": [
      {
         "WSDCOURSECODE": "BTR",
         "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
      },
      {
         "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
         "WSDCOURSECODE": "BYTR",
      }
   ]
};

for (var item in data.COURSEDETAILS) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += data.COURSEDETAILS[item].CDFULLTITLE + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
var json = {
"COURSEDETAILS": {
   "BTR": {
      "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Health Sciences",
   },
   "BYTR": {
      "CDFULLTITLE": "Bachelor of Nursing (Preregistration)",
   }
},
"STUDENT": [
   {
      "WSDCOURSECODE": "BTR",
      "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
   },
   {
      "WSDSTUDENTID": 123456,
      "WSDCOURSECODE": "BYTR",
   }
]
};

for (var i in json.STUDENT) {
  var student = json.STUDENT[i];
  var fulltitle = json.COURSEDETAILS[student.WSDCOURSECODE].CDFULLTITLE;
  //use the title or the student
  console.log(student, fulltitle);
}
```

Comment: sorry I should've said without using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

this fix my problem.

```
data.COURSEDETAILS[data.STUDENT[0].WSDCOURSECODE].CDFULLTITLE
```

Thank you to those who took time to read/reply. :)